# Session invalidation in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I have the following scenario in my web application:

1. All the resources are protected.
2. User starts with log-in screen and the he is forwarded to start page - index.jsp
3. A little time before session expires user is shown a dialog - session is about to expire, click Extend to extend the session, Cancel to cancel it and there is a timer that counts down to session expiration.
4. If user doesn't click anything, I call my servlet that is supposed to expire the session and forward to index.jsp (which should trigger login screen).
   Here is the code for invalidating the session:

   ```
   @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

   if(session != null)
       session.invalidate();

   try {
       request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   }
   ```

My problem is that while it shows the login screen first time in IE, the second time it looks like the session is not invalidated and the main screen just keep refreshing as session is about to expire (the refresh extends the session).

In firefox it doesn't even show login screen the firs time, I see the errors in the console when it goes to the expiration servlet.

What do you think could be the problem?

P.S.
Looks like adding this to the servlet helped in IE:

```
  // Set standard HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers.
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

  // Set IE extended HTTP/1.1 no-cache headers (use addHeader).
  response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");

  // Set standard HTTP/1.0 no-cache header.
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

I need to investigate FF further.

Ok, to answer my question on the FF, the problem was that I was calling the session expiration asynchronously and it had a redirect inside, so this didn't work in FF but did for some reason in IE.

Comment: Why do you need to manually invalidate when the servlet container can invalidate on the timeout.  Your request to the server would revive the session automatically and then you are invalidating it.

Comment: so in IE it works first time and shows login page ? and then you press refresh, it goes to index page? Also can you post firefox console errors

Comment: What exactly is "second time"? Have you excluded the browser cache from being the cause? Track HTTP traffic. Also, why are you trying to invalidate the session when the user doesn't click anything during session expire countdown and thus the session has already expired by end of time?

Comment: I need to manually invalidate because I want the user to see login screen when they are back from long absence. To do this I need to invalidate and go to initial screen.

Comment: Well, I put the window up slightly earlier then the session expiration just to be on the safe side to make sure there are no js timer problems. Actually looks like adding the no-caching helped.

Comment: Actually could be because I use asynch request to do the session expiration:
        var cObj = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('get', '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sessionexpire', function() {});

Comment: *"Actually looks like adding the no-caching helped"* are you implying that your concrete problem is now solved?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, IE now goes to login screen every time after session expiration.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late. But it may be helpful to another one.

As much I understand your problem is that
You want to bring login page after your session is expired. For this you could add the following line of code to your jsp head tag

```
<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval};url=login"></head>
```

it will redirect your page to url mentioned in above code **url** attribute after session is expired.

and you can also add following code to top of your JSP page

```
<%
response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
        "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private, max-age=0");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
%>
<%@page session="true"%>
```

for not cache anything.